# Перенос функций из с++ на другие  языки  которые возвращают строки юникода

Tags: winapi, c++

Если в теле функции именно перед кавычками указываю большую букву L,тогда в другом языке нормально выводит строку

```
_declspec(dllexport) LPTSTR str (LPTSTR str2){    
    str2 = L"строка";
    return str2;    
}
```

Если хочу перенести какую-нибудь готовую функцию возвращающую юникод

```
_declspec(dllexport) void getName(HWND hWnd, LPTSTR name, int n)
{
    int a = GetClassName(      
        hWnd,
        name,
        n);
}
```

Тогда в другом языке выводятся на экран какие-то иероглифы. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ, чтобы можно было указать большую букву L перед переменной содержащей строку юникода  или как-нибудь по-другому? Мне посоветовили использовать динамическую память под буфер, куда возвращается строка, я так пробовал, но все ровно выводятся что-то непонятное. Приведение типов тоже не помогает.

Answer (score 2):

Вы делаете неправильно. Если `str2` есть `LPTSTR`, то и присваивать ей надо не W-string, а T-string, то есть `_T("строка")`.

Для справки: `_T("строка")` — это то же, что и `L"строка"`, если вы компилируете для Unicode-таргета, и то же, что `"строка"` для не-Unicode.

С `getName` вы делаете ещё более неправильно: для того, чтобы вернуть строку из функции, вам нужен *двойной* указатель: иначе изменение параметра `name` не будет видно вызывающей функцией, значение строки останется неинициализированным. (То же справедливо и для первой функции, но там вы хоть возвращаете значение.) Тем не менее, возврат памяти, выделенной в другой DLL, [опасен](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060915-04/?p=29723), будьте осторожны.

Насчёт динамической памяти совет наверняка правильный (если вы собираетесь передавать строку за границу модуля), но он не имеет отношения к вашей текущей проблеме.